# Fix header on vis.js timeline to page

Tags: jquery, html, css, timeline, vis.js

It's great the library [fixes headers now](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/152) within the chart itself, but for us it's halfway there.

Because it's difficult to customise the headers, I added a purpose built row to include some numbers for the month.
Large timelines are painful to scroll vertically, so our users prefer large HTML page they can scroll with, however this of course negates the built in fixed headers.
[image]

I've been exploring code to float either the original header or my content on the page, allowing for page scrolling, but my CSS is not that strong. I've used [this technique](http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/) with success for basic reports, but I'm not sure it's suited here regarding the ability to move the timeline sideways

Any pointers, ideas, suggestions?

Comment: See https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/1534 :D

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by identifying the set of boxes and making them position:fixed in the relevant conditions, ie scrolling down. I saw a similar solution used to fix the headers of a report on scroll.

The last line felt a little dirty, but it works (fn not supplied).

```
   offset_applied = false; // remember if offset applied
   $boxes = $('#p71_timeline .foreground div.group .topbox');

  // when scrolling the page, run this
  $( document ).scroll(function() {
    // if scrolling past where we need to start hovering months, then hover them
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 200) {
       $boxes
          .css(
            {'position':'fixed'  // float month boxes by setting position fixed
            ,'z-index':100       // ensure hover over everything
            ,'top':'44px'        // float below the menu
        });
        // this makes floating boxes a little neater
        $('#shade,#shade_left').show(); 
        // shade_left added to lighten extra months shown when hovering.

      if (!offset_applied) {
        // the first time we need to shift all boxes by an offset probably dependent by y-axis label widths.
        apex.debug('shift right');
        $boxes.css('left','+=247px');
      }
      // only need to do it once, otherwise it quickly zooms to right.
      offset_applied = true;
    }
    else {
      // page scrolled back up to the top, try leave it as we found it
      $boxes.css({'position':'absolute','top':'5px'});
      $('#shade,#shade_left').hide(); 
      if (offset_applied){
        // only need to reverse the offset once
        apex.debug('shift left');
        $boxes.css('left','-=247px');
      }
      offset_applied = false;

    } // scroll position

  });
  // After giving the chart time to render, check box placement.
  // If the page is scrolled down on page load then this needs reapplying.
  setTimeout(function(){_check_placement();}, 1000);
```

I've also rendered a region with part opacity to underlay the boxes when they're hovering (#shade), just to neaten it up.